# can't get Primary Key from kwargs

Tags: django

i have this views.py

```
class AddToCartView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        print(pk)
        if pk is None:
            return Response({"message": "Invalid request"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        item = get_object_or_404(items, pk=pk)
```

i am getting None from `print(pk)`, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any of these two URLs:

```
path('..../<int:pk>/...', AddToCartView, ...)
re_path('..../(?pk[0-9]+)/...', AddToCartView, ...)
```

you can get pk in your view in args of post method.

```
def post(self, request, pk, **kwargs):
    print(pk)
```

If you want something else, let us know.